# Unitary Tensor Representation

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Let V and W be two finite dimensional innerproduct spaces. Suppose (V,$\phi$) & (W,$\rho$) are two Unitary representations of a finite group G. I need to construct an innerproduct on the  Tensor Product space of V & W such that the corresponding Tensor Representation becomes Unitary.

Kindly help!!

Thanks and regards in advance

Comment: If $V$ and $W$ are inner product spaces, then there is a natural candidate for an inner product structure on $V \otimes W$, defined on pure tensors by $\langle v_1 \otimes w_1, v_2 \otimes w_2 \rangle = \langle v_1, v_2 \rangle \langle w_1, w_2 \rangle$. If $S \colon V \to V$ and $T \colon W \to W$ are unitary, then so is $S \otimes T$ under this new inner product.

Comment: I was actually thinking about such innerproduct but I was not sure whether it will satisfy the properties of innerproduct, viz. Linearity in the component , can you help me with that @Joppy?